How to give dashed border to bottom of container in flutter
i want to give a dashed border to just one side of container in flutter i am using dotted border package but it is giving border on all the side of container
i am trying to give a dashed border to bottom of a container in flutter

https://pub.dev/packages/dotted_border

Does this answer your question? How to create a dotted border around a box in flutter?

You can use r_dotted_line_border package which give the controll to give border on one side here is the example:
 Container(
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: RDottedLineBorder(
          bottom: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.red,
      )),
    ),
  )

